# Convert String To Float In C#

Tags: c#, types, type-conversion

I have a function that converts String to different data types. The method works perfectly but if I passed a float value it considers it as a string. So basically any float value with F at the end is considered as a string not a float.

extensionMethods.cs

```
public static object stringConverter(string arg)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(arg, out int i))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("int");
                return i;
            }

            else if (double.TryParse(arg, out double d))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("double");
                return d;
            }

            else if (float.TryParse(arg, out float f))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("float");
                return f;
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("string");

                return arg;
            }
        }
```

Program.cs

```
var fl = extensionMethods.stringConverter("1.1f");
```

The output that I am getting is always a string, not a float. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What motivated you to write your `stringConverter` function? What problem does it solve, exactly?

Comment: @Dai because I am trying to create a program that adds two arguments  which should be passed to the Main function, regardless of what types the arguments

Comment: The "f" at the end is invalid for parsing a number. Why are you adding it in the first place? Also, you could always just parse to double. If it can be a double, it can also be a float and if you truncate it, it can be an into. Returning an "object" just boxes the value and you gain nothing from it, since you have to cast it again anyway.

Comment: If you want to parse `3.14252F` as a float, do it yourself; write a `TryParseMyFloat` that checks if the last character is an `F`, and if so, does a `float.TryParse` on the rest

Comment: I think you are confusing the way numbers are written in C# as *literals*, and the way `Parse` expects them to be, which is just a number with no suffix.

Answer (score 1):

You have two major flaws.

1. In your if/else blocks, you're only checking if it's a float, and is not being detected because technically speaking, `1.1f` isn't a float. However since your float ends with the letter F, the easiest way if to check if the string ends with the letter f, using the function, `else if (arg.EndsWith("f")`. This will enable us to enter the code block.
2. You need to remove the `f` while parsing the float. You can do that using `arg.TrimEnd('f', 'F')` for both upper and lowercase fs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you trying to solve with such method, but...

Single.TryParse accepts just numbers. It doesn't understand "f" at the end, so parsing is failed.
Also if you will pass just 1.1 without "F" the method will convert it to double, not float.

So I suggest you to remove conversion to float. Or you can check arg.EndsWith("f") as Noubar K. suggested.

Also I recommend you to use pascal naming convention for method names in C#.